# Unknown column '9NM2FL1A' in 'where clause' [1054]

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i have a problem with update my column in mysql i confused how to resolve my problem its looks every thing is ok but i have error:

Unknown column '9NM2FL1A' in 'where clause' [1054]

Guys i have this column in my table and its named serialnumber but i don't know why have such error :(

```
$serial = "9NM2FL1A";
$userID = "20";
$reasonString = "bala";

$sql = "SELECT serialnumber FROM lol WHERE serialnumber = '" . $serial . "'";
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
if (empty($row))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO lol (serialnumber,user_id) VALUES ('" . $serial . "','".$userID."')";
    $db->sql_query($sql);
}
$sql = 'UPDATE lol SET pf_can_play = 2, pf_can_play_expire = ' . (time() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)) . ', pf_can_play_reason = \'' . $reasonString . '\', pf_can_has_servers = 1 WHERE serialnumber = ' . $serial;
$db->sql_query($sql);
```

and i must say with bottom query for last 2lines in my code its work as well but i need to check   "WHERE serialnumber = ' . $serial;"

```
$sql = 'UPDATE lol SET pf_can_play = 2, pf_can_play_expire = ' . (time() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)) . ', pf_can_play_reason = \'' . $reasonString . '\', pf_can_has_servers = 1 WHERE user_id = ' . $userID;
$db->sql_query($sql);
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around your string value

Comment: ^^^ Here --> `WHERE serialnumber = ' . $serial;` The variable `$serial` needs single quotes.

Comment: pleas can you tell  me where ?!

Comment: how can you show me :D  i tested with   ' . $serial . '; and also  '".$serial."' but fail

Comment: In its current form, you need `WHERE serialnumber = \'' . $serial . '\'';` but I would recommend changing the entire `UPDATE` statement to be surrounded in double quotes rather than single, so you don't need to backslash-escape them and can directly interpolate the `$serial` variable. (Make sure it is correctly escaped if it comes from user input)

Comment: You appear to be using a custom MySQL wrapper class. Assuming that class is wrapping the old `mysql_*()` functions, now is the time to begin upgrading it to use PDO or MySQLi. The `mysql_*()` API was deprecated last year and will eventually be removed from PHP.

Comment: and also thahk you too @Michael Berkowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'UPDATE lol SET pf_can_play = 2, pf_can_play_expire = ' . (time() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)) . ', pf_can_play_reason = \'' . $reasonString . '\', pf_can_has_servers = 1 WHERE serialnumber = ' . $serial;
```

to

```
$sql = 'UPDATE lol SET pf_can_play = 2, pf_can_play_expire = ' . (time() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)) . ', pf_can_play_reason = \'' . $reasonString . '\', pf_can_has_servers = 1 WHERE serialnumber = \'' . $serial ."'";
                                                                                                                                                                                            Here^^     and here^^^
```

I am always using double quotes to buld the $sql string, to allow myself to use single quotes in it. But now, i just escaped.

Answer (score 0):

TRy like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE lol SET pf_can_play = 2, pf_can_play_expire = ". (time() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 7)) . ", pf_can_play_reason = '".$reasonString."', pf_can_has_servers = 1 WHERE serialnumber = '". $serial."';";
```

The error i think was in this part:

```
 ' . $userID;
```

because is not ant int value you need to add '". $serial."';";